# Examples compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

At the moment I try to understand the topic "proving compact sets".
2 examples: I want to ask, if my assumptions/conclusions are right.

Example 1:

$(x_1-1)^3 + x_2 \le 0\:,\:x_2\ge0$

This set is closed because there are just greater/less than equal signs.
This set is not bounded, because if $x_1$ goes to minus infinity, it is in the set.

Example 2:

$ x^2+y^2 \le 9\:,\: x^2 + y \ge 3$

This set is closed because there are just greater/less than equal signs. This set is also bounded, because negative values are not possible (because of the square is positiv, it is bounded by 9).

Comment: It seems that you have correctly concluded that the set defined by the first set of inequalities is *not* compact, while the set defined by the second set of inequalities *is* compact.

Comment: It seems that a) you talk about subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ - you might have wanted to specify that - and b) you talk about closed and bounded sets "instead" of compact sets

Answer (score 1):

You are correct both times.

Of course you need to give an argument as to *why* they are compact, but drawing a picture often helps.

This is the [first one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28x-1%29%5E3%2By%5Cleq%200%20and%20y%5Cgeq%200) in Wolfram Alpha, and this is the [second one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%5Cleq%209%20and%20x%5E2%2By%5Cgeq%203). Notice how the second one is just a disc, but where you have removed a parabola-shaped section of it.

Comment: great, thank you very much for your answer! Would it be sufficient to prove: if x --> infinity, it is in the set, and so it is possible, that there is always a point outside the "ball around the set"?

Comment: @lars111 If you are talking about example $1$, maybe you mean $x_1\to -\infty$. The solution set can never be contained in any ball, since $x_1$ can become arbitrarily large in the negative direction.